# VBA Loop to update a hyperlink for each cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have edited this question because I made a small mistake and decided not to dumb down the cell references I am using to simple ones.

I have chosen to update a hyperlink in a specific cell by running a macro.

```
Range("AB118").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
Range("Z118") & Range("AD105")
```

So basically:

Column AB contains the final hyperlink Eg. Home!AB118

Column Z contains the name of the sheet Eg. Home!

Cell AD105 contains the cell which you will land Eg. AB118

I have written the macro to update the hyperlink one cell/row at a time.

```
 'Update "Sheet 1" Link
    Range("AB118").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    Range("Z118") & Range("AD105")

'Update "Sheet 2" Link
    Range("AB119").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    Range("Z119") & Range("AD105")

'Update "Sheet 3" Link
    Range("AB120").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    Range("Z120") & Range("AD105")
```

Is there a way to use "For Each" or similar, to shorten this macro which goes through each line combining column Z & cell AD105 into a hyperlink which appears in Column AB.

Hopefully this will make sense, I'm quite experienced with excel and VBA, but new to the forum.

The table of this information starts at row 118 and ends at row 171, So I am not sure if I need to tell it to start on a specific row and end on a specific row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an error in your code to perform the hyperlink if this isn’t addressed in the cell value. You need to make sure it the reference is setup like a sheet range reference.

```
SubAddress:= Range("Z118") & Range("AD105")
```

Should be

```
SubAddress:= "'" & Range("Z118") &"'!" & Range("AD105")
```

But since this is handled in you cell values, you have a couple options from here. But here is a For loop like you asked for (see TinMan464 for a While loop):

```
Sub foo() 
Dim i as integer 

  For i = 118 to 200 ‘change the last number to what you need 
     Range("AB"&i).Select
     ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= "'" & Range("Z"&i) &"'!" &  Range("AD105")
  Next i

End sub
```

But I would avoid using [select](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate)

```
Sub foo()
Dim i as integer

  For i = 1 to 3 ‘change the last number to what you need 
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:= Range("AB"&i), Address:="", SubAddress:= "'" & Range("Z"&i) &"'!" &  Range("AD105")
  Next i

End sub
```

Comment: Am I able to respond with more examples? This comment box doesn't have  much formatting capability. I can't even seem to work out how to start a new line!?

Comment: Thanks for that recent update - I actually type the extra punctuation into the cell so that it is pulled through to the link by the sub

Comment: Oh okay. Does my update help you with Ranges? Do you need me to take out the extra punctuation?

Comment: Wow that was quick. Well done. That would be mega helpful. I am a bit confused by your response though, how do I use this in a sub? Do I need to "Dim i as Integer" before hand?

Comment: I added the sub name and the integer declaration. It’s good practices to explicitly declare your variables, but unless you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, isn’t required.

Comment: Legend. Is there a way to send messages on this to users.

Comment: Nah I don’t think so. [Found this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: Yes It works. Except you were right by saying 'You need to make sure it the reference is setup like a sheet range reference.' it worked without in my original code, but not in the new without this addition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Sub to cycle through Column "B" and "C" until one of them is empty.  This will populate Column "A" with the values from "B" and "C" until there are no more contiguous values left.

```
Private Sub NewLink()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Range("B" & i).Value) Or IsEmpty(Range("C" & i).Value)
        Range("A" & i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        Range("B" & i) & Range("C" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Just use the following to call this function wherever you need it/want it to run.

```
Call NewLink
```

Following Dude_Scott's recommendation for .Select, use the following.

```
Private Sub NewLink()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do Until IsEmpty(Range("B" & i).Value) Or IsEmpty(Range("C" & i).Value)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A" & i), Addreess:="", SubAddress:= _
        Range("B" & i) & Range("C" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

EDIT: To assist readers in selecting a proper solution for their needs.

The pros to the 'Do While' loop are that you can add additional, consecutive rows without having to update your macro/sub.

The cons are that columns "B" and "C" are essentially reserved for creating links in column "A".

Answer (score 1):

We already have an accepted answer using a standard `For` loop, but here is a version using `For Each`, `With`, and `Offset` for reference:

```
Dim WorkingCell As Range

For Each WorkingCell In ActiveSheet.Range("AB118:AB171").Cells
    With WorkingCell
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(1,1), Address:="", _
            SubAddress:=.Offset(0,-2).Value & ActiveSheet.Range("AD105").Value
    End With
Next WorkingCell
```

Comment: When I run this, I get "Runtime error 450. Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assigned."

Comment: I believe you’re getting an error with the anchor. Your are trying to reference a cell with the WorkingCell object. I think for this to work it should read `Anchor:= WorkingCell`

Comment: @MattCann Sorry, I forgot that `Address` is a mandatory Parameter, even when it is not used.  I have added `Address:="", ` to the code

Comment: @Dude_Scott As `WorkingCell` is a 1-cell range, `WorkingCell`, `WorkingCell.Cells(1,1)` and `WorkingCell.Range` are all equivalent.  Because this is in a `With`, we can drop the `WorkingCell` (I used `.Cells(1,1)` because thought `Anchor:=.Range` might be less clear to beginners trying to learn from the example)